# Can commutativity be deduced from associativity, identity, and inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I have a function $\#$ on the integers. For all $x \in\Bbb Z$, $x\#0=x$. For all $x \in\Bbb Z$, an inverse $y$ exists such that $x\#y=0$. The operation is associative, but not necessarily commutative. Can it be deduced that $\#$ is commutative?

Comment: Associativity, identity, and inverses to *not* imply commutativity; not even two-sided identity and two-sided inverses. The symmetric group on 3 elements proves that. Even if you add that the group needs to be infinite, it is still not forced.

Comment: No.  There are countable non-abelian groups.

Comment: If you inspect my edit, you'll see how to "escape" characters like #. You should put dollar signs around entire expressions.

Comment: @Robert Israel What about GL(2,Q)?

Comment: @Subhajit What about it?